# SQL как получить список пользователей которые имели определенный возраст на момент целевого действия

Tags: sql

таблица A:

```
UserID | Birthaday (в формате 1988-03-10)
```

Таблица B:

```
UserID | Actiondate (в формате 2018-10-24 14:28:16.307)
```

**Задача**: получить список юзеров, которым на момент целевого действия было менее 65 лет. Помогите составить условие "Where".

Comment: RTFM `DATEDIFF()`

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!)))

Comment: @ПавелВасильев а вы оформите то, что у вас получилось ответом. Возможно кому нибудь потом ваш ответ окажется полезным

Comment: @ПавелВасильев надеюсь, вы учли, что `SELECT DATEDIFF(YEAR, '20001231', '20650101')` вернет 65? Подсчет в столбик говорит, что эти даты отличаются на 64 года и 1 день.